# Can we put a char digit into an int Stack in C programming language?

Tags: c

We're given a char arithmetic expression and we should put the operands into an int stack and solve the expression with the operator and get the answer. Is it possible passing a character into a integer stack and get the answer?

Comment: A `char` fits in an `int`, so your answer is *yes*.

Comment: C does not have a special character type. `char` is an integer type.

Comment: @Quentin: That is not true for all implementations (and not required by the standard).

Comment: @Olaf I'm dead certain that `int` has to be at least as big as `char`, but I'll check again. Edit: from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types): "Besides the minimal bit counts, the C Standard guarantees that
`1 == sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`"

Comment: @Quentin: `sizeof(int) >= sizeof(char)`. But that does not mean an `int` can represent all values of a `char`. Take into account that `char` has no standard signed-ness and there might be padding-bits in `int`, but not in `char` (not sure if that would allow `SCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX, though)!

Comment: @Olaf very good point, I didn't think about signedness at all. One day it'll bite me and then I'll remember :)

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, C is always good for another pitfall.

Comment: @Olaf: How would -127 to 127 or 0 to  255 not fit into -32767 to 32767?

Comment: Ahok "*... shall be equal or **greater** in magnitude ...*" *sigh*

Comment: @alk: How do you know those are the actual limit of `char` in OPs (or any other reader's) target? You silently premise `CHAR_BIT == 8`. Ok, I was too slow typing. Another trap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible passing a character into a integer

Yes, this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_me(signed char c; int i)
{
  printf("'%c' = %d\n", c, i);
}

int main(void)
{
  signed char c = 'A';
  int i = c;

  print_me(c, i);

  ...
```

Assuming ASCII character encoding this would print:

```
'A' = 65
```